# Imposible instalar Reporting Services 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Tengo un equipo con Windows 10 y SQL Server 2017 Estandar instalado. Estoy tratando de instalar el Reporting Services (que veo que ahora la instalación del mismo es independiente), pero cuando ejecuto en ejecutable que se descarga de la web de Microsoft, se abre el proceso del instalador y se cierra a los 3-4 segundos sin mostrar nada.

Tengo instalado .NET Framework 4.6.2, siendo el mínimo que pide el 4.5.2

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo.

Resulta que Microsoft había subido una versión nueva justo ayer y estaba mal. Han vuelto a la versión anterior del instalador.

Me estaba volviendo loco ya.